# How to Access modified global variable in init.py into another module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I am looking for a pythonic way to access a global variable(profit_benchmark) which is defined inside a __init__.py file and it's value modified in one of the modules(routines.py) and now I wanted to access profit_benchmark with modified value in another module(network.py)

Here is my folder structue:

[image]

__init__.py

```
profit_benchmark = 50
```

routines.py

```
from so import profit_benchmark
profit_benchmark = 60
```

network.py

```
from so import profit_benchmark
print(profit_benchmark)
```

**Output:**

```
50
```

I am expecting an output of 60 because variable profit_benchmark modified in routine.py

My Question: How can I access the new value of profit_benchmark variable in network.py so that ouput will be 60

Comment: The Pythonic way would be not to rely on global mutable state, and that is just a general programming best-practice. Anyway, your import creates a *new local variable* . You can just `import so` and use `so.profit_benchmark`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so how do i know if global variable is changed if we don't rely on that. what's the best practice to know the modified status of global variable.

Comment: min2bro: @juanpa.arrivillaga just told you the "best practice".

Comment: @martineau that doesn't work importing profit_benchmark from so still gives the old value i.e. 50 . I tried so.profit_benchmark

Comment: @min2bro this was juanpa's adivce not martineau's one, and it seems you didn't read it well enough - he told you to replace the `from so import profit_benchmark` statements with `import so` and then to always use `so.profit_benchmark` - and this WILL work.

Comment: This works..Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @min2bro you don't understand, the best practice is  **you shouldn't modifying global variables**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: Python doesn't have real globals, only module-level globals - each module is a distinct namespace and a global is only 'global' to the module it's defined in.

Second thing: the `import` statement is nothing like a C or PHP `include` - it doesn't "copy" the whole imported module in the importing one, but loads the imported module (if it hasn't been loaded already) and make it available in the importing namespace

Actually, this:

```
import so
```

is a shortcut for

```
from importlib import importmodule
so = importmodule("so")
```

and this:

```
from so import profit_benchmark
```

is a shortcut for

```
from importlib import importmodule
so = importmodule("so")
profit_benchmark = so.profit_benchmark
del so
```

As juanpa (briefly) explained, in this second case, what happens is that you end up with two names (`so.profit_benchmark` and `your_importing_module.profit_benchmark`) both pointing to the same object.

Now Python variables aren't C-style memory location, they are name=>object entries in a namespace (mostly, key:value pairs in a dict). Assignment actually just make the assigned named point to another object, so when you do

```
from so import profit_benchmark
profit_benchmark = 42
```

the first statement creates the name "profit_benchmark" **in the current namespace** and binds it to the same object as what `so.profit_benchmark` points to, and the second statement rebinds the current namespace's `profit_benchmark` *name* to the `42` int object, **leaving `so.profit_benchmark` totally unchanged**. All this (and much more very useful things to know) is explained in great depths in [this Ned Batchelder's article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

On the other hand when you do

```
import so
so.profit_benchmark = 42
```

the name you are rebinding is effectively `so`'s "global" `profit_benchmark` - which has actually become an attribute of the `so` module object (at runtime, modules are objects too), so any other module reading `so.profit_benchmark` will now get the updated value.

**This being said**: you asked for "the pythonic way", and the pythonic way is actually to avoid mutable global state as much as possible (and that's one of the reasons why python's "globals" aren't truly globals). And the fact is that once you get into the habit of using pure functions as much as possible and classes when you need to have *some* shared state between a state of functions, you realize you can write very large programs without a single "writable" global (nb: read-only globals are of course perfectly ok, the problems begin when you start mutating or - even worse - rebinding globals).

So the question is: why do you think you need a writable global at all ? There are many ways to avoid them, but the "correct" solution(s) depends on the concrete use case, which you say nothing about.

Comment: You will agree with me that there are cases where you would need to update the global variables just to let the downstream process to be aware of the current status of the global variable. For example: I would like to do a intermittent health checkup on one of the services and want to pass this status every state. best way to store the health in a global variable and pass on rather than hitting the server at every stage

Comment: So what I mean is I really don't understand that why everyone is advocating for not modifying the global variable. It's all about the use case that you have in hand

Comment: @min2bro I won't agree with anything until I've seen the specs and the code - there are many ways to skin a cat ;-) And everyone is just stating what they learned by experience: the less mutable global state you have, the better. For more "restricted" mutable state, you have classes and objects. And of course functions arguments...